# scroll to a list-item after angular has rendered the element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to scroll to the last message in the chat box. So I am doing it as -

```
akiRepair.controller("chatCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
...
    var size = $scope.messages.length;
    var t = document.querySelector("#chat-box");
      console.log(t);
      var elt = angular.element(t.querySelector("md-list-item")[size-1]);

      angular.element("#chat-box").animate({scrollTop: elt.offset().top}, "slow");
```

Now before ng-repeat completes is rendering the controller code is run, which I don't want. is there any way to suspend "scroll to" function until everything is rendered properly.

HTML CODE -

```
<md-list layout-padding id="chat-box">
      <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages">
          <i class="md-avatar material-icons"
          ng-if="message.sender">face</i>
          <div class="md-list-item-text"
          ng-class="message.sender?'left-align':'right-align'">
            <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
            <h4 class="faded">{{message.whence | date: 'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'}}</h4>
          </div>
          <i class="md-avatar material-icons"
          ng-if="!message.sender">face</i>
          <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
      </md-list-item>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Your delayed code goes here
});
```

Without specifying a delay as a second parameter, the passed function will be called immediately after the curren thread of execution that finishes with rendering of the page.

You can also use the $`timeout` service offered by angular (a wrapper around `setTimeout`) but it does not give you any benefits here. It only triggers another digest cycle that is not necessary.

Comment: Great that worked, however the animate function is not working, can you please suggest something for that also

Comment: About your comment that `$timeout` is not necessary here, true, but it helps for testing since you can pretty easily mock it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom directive to your **`ng-repeat`** portion like this & add scroll option to that directive like this

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages" my-repeat-directive>
    <i class="md-avatar material-icons"
       ng-if="message.sender">face</i>
    <div class="md-list-item-text"
         ng-class="message.sender?'left-align':'right-align'">
        <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
        <h4 class="faded">{{message.whence | date: 'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'}}</h4>
    </div>
    <i class="md-avatar material-icons"
       ng-if="!message.sender">face</i>
    <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
</md-list-item>

akiRepair.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            angular.element("#chat-box").animate({scrollTop: elt.offset().top}, "slow");
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: yeah I tried it, it worked. However the animate function is not working, can you please help me how to do a scroll to animation with angular js

Comment: nope I don't have jquery only angularjs and other angular support libs

Comment: @codeomnitrix you can check this article https://coderwall.com/p/hujlhg/smooth-scrolling-without-jquery but I suggest you use jQuery as it will save a lot of time for situations like this.